# Converting JSON string to object in jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have a jQuery http request which returns me an object in the form of JSON string. Here what I have to do is convert the JSON to the jQuery object and assign the values to html elements... the following is the structure of the object to be converted:

```
var Userrights = {

            Id: // an id element
            ScreenRights: // this is a list with following elements
            {
                ScreenName: 
                Create:
                Read: 
                Update: 
                Delete:
                Approve: 
                Access: 
                Print: 
                Email: 
            };
        };
```

Now when I receive a JSON String like the following:

```
{
    "Id": "Manager",
    "ScreenRights": [{
        "ScreenName": "CustomerScreen",
        "Create": true,
        "Read": false,
        "Update": true,
        "Delete": false,
        "Approve": true,
        "Access": true,
        "Print": true,
        "Email": true
    },
    {
        "ScreenName": "TraderScreen",
        "Create": true,
        "Read": false,
        "Update": true,
        "Delete": false,
        "Approve": true,
        "Access": true,
        "Print": true,
        "Email": true
    },
    {
        "ScreenName": "DistributorScreen",
        "Create": true,
        "Read": false,
        "Update": true,
        "Delete": false,
        "Approve": true,
        "Access": true,
        "Print": true,
        "Email": true
    }]
}​
```

Now how will I convert this String to above mentioned object Structure?

Comment: What is you problem? The JSON has almost the desired form, so just parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery:

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(string);
console.log(obj);
```

With that said, if you are using jQuery's .ajax you could just set `dataType:'json'`

Comment: Thanks. but can you just say me how i could access the list in that object or an element in that object. And how i could loop around that list please.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can push your json inside some array, then you can make the loop accessing the object by name.

```
result[i].Create;
result[i].Read;
```